# Why aren't injector pumps used in rockets?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, liquid-fuel, turbopump

Is there something that makes [injectors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injector) unsuitable as oxidizer pumps? Seems to me that rockets would benefit significantly from a pump with no moving parts that runs off its own exhaust.

Comment: What's the max pressure an injector pump can deliver? I seem to remember them as low pressure.

Comment: The first problem I see is that if the exhaust isn't completely combusted when it enters the injector, it's liable to ignite the incoming propellant at the mixing stage. This may be less of a problem for a fuel pump if the exhaust is already fuel-rich (typical in most rocket engines)?

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem for hybrid rockets though

Comment: re: hybrid rockets, solid propellant exhaust tends to contain a lot of particles, etc, and shooting this into a stream of oxidizer sounds exciting but not in a good way.

Comment: Hmmm...monopropellant oxidizer(N20/H2O2) + catalyst could generate clean motive fluid for it.